# JavaFX shape on click

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-2

So I am currently creating this API. this login class should just create a scene with all of the needed boxes in it to make a GUI. The problem I am having is that my shapes won't do anything when clicked. I have the event listener but it won't work.

```
    import java.awt.Container;
    import javafx.application.*;
    import javafx.event.EventHandler;
    import javafx.stage.*;
    import javafx.scene.*;
    import javafx.scene.layout.*;
    import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
    import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle;
    import javafx.scene.text.Font;
    import javafx.scene.text.Text;
    import javafx.scene.text.TextAlignment;
    import javafx.scene.control.*;
    import javafx.scene.image.Image;
    import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
    import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent;

public class Login extends MainWindow {
private Stage primaryStage;
public static boolean ifContractor=false;
public static boolean ifClient=false;
private static Group root;
private static ImageView iv;

Login(){

}
public static Scene loginScreen(){
    root = new Group();
    fillBackround();
    createShapes();
    System.out.println("I AM ROOT 3 : "+root);

    Scene loginScene = new Scene(root, 1000,750);
    return loginScene;
}
public static void fillBackround() {
    Image loginBackround = new Image("loginBackround.jpg",true);
    iv = new ImageView();
    iv.setImage(loginBackround);
    root.getChildren().add(iv); 

}
public static void createShapes() {
    Group shapes = new Group();
    Rectangle mainBox = mainBox();
    Pane cornerBox = cornerBox();
    Pane clientBox = clientBox();
    Pane contractorBox = contractorBox();

    shapes.getChildren().addAll(mainBox,cornerBox,clientBox,contractorBox);
    root.getChildren().add(shapes);
}
public static Rectangle mainBox() {
    Rectangle mainBox = new Rectangle(350,100,300,500);
    mainBox.setStroke(Color.BLUE);
    mainBox.setFill(Color.DODGERBLUE);
    mainBox.setStrokeWidth(3);
    mainBox.setArcWidth(25);
    mainBox.setArcHeight(25);
    mainBox.setOpacity(0.5);
    return mainBox;

}
public static Pane cornerBox() {
    Rectangle cornerBox = new Rectangle(350,100,250,75);
    cornerBox.setStroke(Color.BLUE);
    cornerBox.setFill(Color.DODGERBLUE);
    cornerBox.setStrokeWidth(3);
    cornerBox.setArcWidth(25);
    cornerBox.setArcHeight(25);
    cornerBox.setOpacity(0.5);
    Text cornerText = new Text(370,150, null);
    cornerText.setFont(new Font(25));
    cornerText.setFill(Color.WHITESMOKE);
    cornerText.setWrappingWidth(200);
    cornerText.setTextAlignment(TextAlignment.JUSTIFY);
    cornerText.setText("Login as: ");
    Pane cornerStack = new Pane();
    cornerStack.getChildren().addAll(cornerBox,cornerText);
    return cornerStack;
}
public static Pane clientBox() {
    Rectangle clientBox = new Rectangle(400,300,200,75);
    clientBox.setStroke(Color.BLUE);
    clientBox.setFill(Color.DODGERBLUE);
    clientBox.setStrokeWidth(3);
    clientBox.setArcWidth(25);
    clientBox.setArcHeight(25);
    clientBox.setOnMousePressed(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>()
    {
        @Override
        public void handle(MouseEvent t) {  
            ifClient = true;   
            System.out.println("Has been clicked");
        }
    });
    Text clientText = new Text(450,350, null);
    clientText.setFont(new Font(25));
    clientText.setFill(Color.WHITESMOKE);
    clientText.setWrappingWidth(200);
    clientText.setTextAlignment(TextAlignment.JUSTIFY);
    clientText.setText("CLIENT");
    Pane clientStack = new Pane();
    clientStack.getChildren().addAll(clientBox,clientText);
    return clientStack;
}
public static Pane contractorBox() {
    Rectangle contractorBox = new Rectangle(400,400,200,75);
    contractorBox.setStroke(Color.BLUE);
    contractorBox.setFill(Color.DODGERBLUE);
    contractorBox.setStrokeWidth(3);
    contractorBox.setArcWidth(25);
    contractorBox.setArcHeight(25);
    Text contractorText = new Text(415,450, null);
    contractorText.setFont(new Font(25));
    contractorText.setFill(Color.WHITESMOKE);
    contractorText.setWrappingWidth(200);
    contractorText.setTextAlignment(TextAlignment.JUSTIFY);
    contractorText.setText("CONTRACTOR");
    Pane contractorStack = new Pane();
    contractorStack.getChildren().addAll(contractorBox,contractorText);
    return contractorStack;
}

}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. While it is a good start to have an example in your question, it should be executable for these type of questions. Please take a minute to look at how to post a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is your `Panes` are overlapping each other. When you call this:

```
shapes.getChildren().addAll(mainBox,cornerBox,clientBox,contractorBox);
```

`contractorBox` (which is a Pane) will be on the top, consuming all of the click events.

You should use the same pane in all of your methods instead. For that you could use a member like:

```
private static Pane pane = new Pane();
```

then for example in `cornerBox`:

```
pane.getChildren().addAll(cornerBox,cornerText);
```

**This is a solution for this case, BUT:**

This whole class looks strange. Why are you extending MainWindow? Makes no sense. Also why everyting is static?

What you would need, a class extending any `Parent` (e.g. `Group`) , which fills up the Parent with every control you want, and returns the Parent. Then you could you it anywhere you want as:

```
Scene scene = new Scene(new Login());
```

I also don't understand why are you drawing rectangles and texts. What you basically need is two buttons. You can modify the look of buttons using CSS: [Example1](http://fxexperience.com/2011/12/styling-fx-buttons-with-css/), [Example2](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/get_started/css.htm).

Comment: So I have a class Drawingpane which creates the whole window. Than in main window it loads the scene depending on conditional statements. If user clicks client box in login than main window will open a new scene. Im not sure if this is the best way to do it honestly

Comment: The solution for the current implementation is above: use the same Pane in cornerBox, clientBox and contractorBox rather than creating new Panes in every method. The answer also includes how shall it be implemented instead :)

Comment: Thanks you are awesome!